# Equivalent for "both" for three or more entities

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Which words could I use for (1) and (2) below:

> two => both
>   three => (1)?
>   four => (2)?

To use them in phrases like these:

> *both* A and B
>   (1) A, B and C
>   (2) A, B, C and D

Please give single words if possible.

Comment: "all" seems obvious

Comment: There's none that I know of, for both of your examples.

Comment: In some cases, "both" is an unnecessary word, so you may not need an equivalent.  Can you use "both" in a sentence?